# Enabling TCP Transport for WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm experimenting with different transports supported by WSO2 ESB. I want to enable TCP Transport for WSO2 ESB. I've downloaded the `axis2-transport-tcp-1.0.0.jar` and placed it into `ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib`. I managed to enable Transport Sender by adding

```
<transportSender name="tcp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportSender"/>
```

to `axis2.xml` configuration file. In order to enable Transport Receiver I've added a similar line

```
<transportReceiver name="tcp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPServer"/>
```

However this fails to initialize the Transport Receiver when I restart WSO2 ESB. Instead I get an `InstantiationError`:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occured while loading the Axis configuration from /usr/local/wso2esb/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:190)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.createNewConfigurationContext(CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.java:65)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:398)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:290)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPServer
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportReceivers(AxisConfigBuilder.java:643)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:130)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.populateAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:308)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:188)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPServer
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportReceivers(AxisConfigBuilder.java:627)
    ... 11 more
```

I've tried supplying port number parameter in `axis2.xml` but nothing changed.

I've tried to trace the Error. It seems that class object can not be instantiated due to absence of no-parameter constructor. But I've run the following example without any error by using the same jar files:

```
String className = "org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPServer";
Class receiverClass;

receiverClass = Loader.loadClass(className);

TransportListener receiver = (TransportListener) receiverClass.newInstance();
```

I guess it is an integration problem but I could not come up with any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable TCP transport you do not have to add the "axis2-transport-tcp-1.0.0.jar" its nessasary libraries are shipped with WSO2 ESB.

All you have to do is go to axis2.xml available in

```
ESB_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
```

and add following blocks for Transport sender and Transport Reciver
here you can add the tcp port by adding

```
<parameter name="transport.tcp.port">6060</parameter>
```

As shown below.
For transport receiver

```
<!-- Enable TCP message -->  
<transportReceiver name="tcp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportListener">
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.port">6060</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

To add Transport Sender

```
<transportSender name="tcp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportSender"/>
```

Thank You,
Dharshana.

Comment: I figured that I've used org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPServer instead of org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportListener. Official documentation does not specify any class in XML declaration and specifies that org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPServer is the implementing class. That was what misguided me.